# Trying to make Status bar and Navigation bar translucent, not transparent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make my first app for a school project. I got the status bar translucent at times by following other people questions and answers but the nav just goes grey but with no contents from the activity BUT the navigation drawer draws below both status and navigation bar, how can I make the activity to draw below status and nav bar as well?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmvMg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1n5F.jpg)

code for image 2 is, under onCreate:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
```

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);

And I tried with    `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and without, kinda hard to understand it all already.

Comment: did you try remove android:fitsSystemWindows and FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS?

Comment: yes, and I get primary dark color in status bar and black color in navigation bar, and nothing is behind them. https://i.imgur.com/X2r2vV8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much solved by adding these two lines in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Not the most elegant because I don't have a proper toolbar? I think. I need to put `android:layout_marginTop="24dp"` in activity_main.xml and pretty much everywhere else where I may have buttons at the top of the app.